# Primefaces f:setPropertyActionListener inside p:dataGrid is only working on first register

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, el

I'm using primefaces-4.0 and getting a really strange behavior.

There's a collection of layouts `layoutMateriaMB.listaLayouts` and I iterate on it creating a `p:dataGrid` where each column represents a Layout and the `f:setPropertyActionListener` of that column sets in the Bean the selected layout. The first column works fine, when clicked it calls the setLayout method in `layoutMateriaMB`, however, all other columns do not work. The set method just isn't called and I can't see why this is happening.

Here follows my code:

```
<p:dataGrid var="layout" value="#{layoutMateriaMB.listaLayouts}" columns="5" rows="1" paginator="false">
    <p:column>
        <p:panel header="#{layout.valor}" style="text-align:center">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
                <h:graphicImage library="imagens/layouts" name="#{layout.imagem}" width="100" />
                <p:commandLink update=":form:grid-layout" oncomplete="" title="Selecionar" rendered="#{layoutMateriaMB.layout ne layout}">
                    <h:outputText value="Selecionar" title="Selecionar" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{layout}" target="#{layoutMateriaMB.layout}" immediate="true"/>
                </p:commandLink>
                <h:outputText value="Selecionado" title="Selecionado" rendered="#{layoutMateriaMB.layout eq layout}" style="color:#313964; font-weight:bold;"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
```

---

Ok, I solved the problem. It was as simple ans changing `rows="1"` to `rows="5"`.
That solved the problem and all items are working correctly. But I still can't see why it wasn't working. If anybody knows it, please let me know.. :)

Comment: Not sure why either, but your solution works..thank you!!!!

Comment: It worked for me, too! In fact, `rows` seems to need a number equal or greater than the number of columns. When I had 3 columns and `row="2"`, only the two first items were working. When I set `rows="3"`, the three of them were working!